# How can I store numbers into array every time I input a new number from keyboard (java)?

Tags: java, arrays, input, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class smth {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      int array[]={};

}
```

what can i do next, to store every number I input from keyboard into array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
          ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            int check=0;
            while(true){
                check = input.nextInt();
                if(check == 0) break;
                al.add(check);

            }

            for (int i : al) {
                System.out.print(i);
            }


}
```

That's what I did. When user enters "0", it breaks.

Answer (score 3):

A `while()` loop involving the Scanner object would be beneficial.  You don't need to reinitialize/redeclare it every time through the loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class smth {
    final int SIZE = 10; // You need to define a size.
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int array[]= new int[SIZE];

    public void readFromTerminal() {
        System.out.println("Read lines, please enter some other character to stop.");
        String in = input.nextLine();
        while ( ) { } // I encourage you to fill in the blanks!
    }
}
```

[EDIT]  If you want the user to be able to enter an *"unlimited"* number of integers, then an [`ArrayList<Integer>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/ArrayList.html) would be more ideal.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class smth {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //  Please reference the documentation to see why I'm using the Integer wrapper class, and not a standard int.

    public void readFromTerminal() {
        System.out.println("Read lines, please enter some other character to stop.");
        String in = input.nextLine();
        while ( ) { } // I encourage you to fill in the blanks!
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem.  Remember, here on SO if you see an answer you like/agree with, don't forget to accept it so the community knows your issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to wrap that in a while loop based on some condition. For now, it can just be `while(true)...`, but later on you are going to want to use a condition that will terminate at some point.

Comment: And I agree with @Makoto, you can initialize the scanner outside of the loop so that it is only done once.